# Usage of 'but' in a sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In this passage from Book III, passage 2 of Sun Tzu's [*The Art of War*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/132/132-h/132-h.htm#chap11), does Lionel Giles use of the square-bracketed "but"  effectively make the first sentence convey the meaning that **ALL modern strategists would approve the words of the Chinese general**?

> Here again, no modern strategist [but] will approve the words of the old Chinese general. Moltke's greatest triumph, the capitulation of the huge French army at Sedan, was won practically without bloodshed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old-fashioned literary use of *but*.

*No modern strategist but will approve* actually means *every modern strategist will approve*.

It is meaning 3 of [this in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/but#Conjunction) - see the quotation from Keats there.

It can be confusing, and I think that is one reason that it has gone out of use.

Comment: Or in the alternative, *"Here again, no modern strategist will* [do [anything] other than] *approve the words of the old Chinese general."*